# Passing object with prepareForSegue Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard, uistoryboard

I am trying to pass an object to another scene with **prepareForSegue()**

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
        var nextScene =  segue.destinationViewController as! VehicleDetailsTableViewController

        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
            let selectedVehicle = vehicles[indexPath.row]
            nextScene.currentVehicle = selectedVehicle
        }
    }
```

And I have currentVehicle object to catch these object. But, when I try to run, it brokes and get error about downcasting.

**Error EDIT**

> Could not cast value of type 'XXX.DisplayViewController'
>   (0x1082dcd80) to 'XXX.VehicleDetailsTableViewController'
>   (0x1082dc9a0). (lldb)

Comment: You really should be checking that segue identifier to make sure you are correctly casting the destinationViewController. What exactly is the error message you are getting?

Comment: check my question, updated.

Comment: It looks like `segue.destinationViewController` is giving you a `DisplayViewController`  Check connections in storyboard.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You have to give the segue an identifier in the storyboard.(say `mySegue`)

**Using Xcode 10 swift 4.x(Also works with Xcode 9 & 8 , swift 3.x)**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){}
```

Is called for all segues being called from your current `UIViewController`. So the `identifier` is to differentiate the different segues

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "mySegue" , 
       let nextScene = segue.destination as? VehicleDetailsTableViewController , 
       let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        let selectedVehicle = vehicles[indexPath.row]
        nextScene.currentVehicle = selectedVehicle
    }
}
```

**If you are using Using Xcode 7, swift 2.x**

Then use this code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "mySegue" {
    var nextScene =  segue.destinationViewController as! VehicleDetailsTableViewController

    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        let selectedVehicle = vehicles[indexPath.row]
        nextScene.currentVehicle = selectedVehicle
    }
  }
}
```

Place a breakpoint after `nextScene` and see if it is being triggered by clicking any cell in the `TableView`. If it isn't then the identifier name u provided in the storyboard must be different then the one given here.

Comment: Almost worked. **println(currentVehicle?.location** returns nil on secondScene. I don't understand why, normally it has a value I can't pass

Comment: Place a break point after `var nextScene` and see if it is being triggered on clicking any cell in the `TableView`. If it isn't then the identifier name u provided in the storyboard must be different then the one given here.

Answer (score 8):

## In swift 3.0 Xcode 8 beta 6

`AnyObject` has been renamed to `Any?`

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
    let nextScene =  segue.destinationViewController as! VehicleDetailsTableViewController

    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        let selectedVehicle = vehicles[indexPath.row]
        nextScene.currentVehicle = selectedVehicle
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that segue.destinationViewController has been renamed to segue.destination

Comment: this is not a valid answer ... You are not checking for the segue.identifier....This will lead to crash if there are multiple segues

Answer (score 3):

### In Swift 3, Xcode 8

Just don't use "identifier". I don't know why but "segue.identifier" is always nil. I just used prepare method like this and works!

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let secondController = segue.destination as? SecondController {
        secondController.anyItemInSecondController = self.anyItemInFirstController
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

What that error is telling you is that segue.destinationViewController isn't a VehicleDetailsTableViewController. We don't have enough details to tell you why.

Check your segues and make sure they're all pointing to the correct place, and always check the identifier of your segue before you perform a cast.

```
if segue.identifier == "theNameOfYourSegue" // then do your cast
```

Comment: I'd use a switch statement instead of in if, but yeah.

Comment: @Abizern I know this is really old, however, Do you have any good reason for doing so?

Comment: @iShaalan Where there are multiple choices, in this case multiple possible values of the identifier, I find `switch` statement clearer to read.