# fetching data from UItableview cell with id

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

I'm working on a project where there is a list of orders in a UITableView. The orders come from API in JSON format. Each UITableview cell has:

1. name of the shop
2. addresse of the shop
3. client name
4. client address

Also in JSON I have the order_id.

I fetched the data in the UItableview and it's fine. But when the user clicks on one of the orders the view should go to the order details. I get the order details in the next view by a link like this `help/order/2` where 2 is the order number. How can I save the order_id and pass it to the next view to make a call request to fetch the details?

I'm saving the orders in a class like this:

```
class Order {
    private var _date : String?
    private var _logo : String?
    private var _shopname : String?
    private var _shopaddress : String?
    private var _clientName : String?
    private var _ClientAddress : String?
    private var _PerferTime : String?
    private var _Cost : String?

    var date : String{
        return _date!
    }
    var shopname : String{
        return _shopname!
    }
    var shopaddress : String {
        return _shopaddress!
    }
    var clientName : String {
        return _clientName!
    }
    var ClientAddress : String{
        return _ClientAddress!
    }
    var PerferTime : String{
        return _PerferTime!
    }
    var Cost : String{
        return _Cost!
    }
    var Logo : String{
        return _logo!
    }

    init(shopname : String , shopaddress :String,clientName : String , ClientAddress : String, PerferTime : String , Cost : String , date:String , Logo : String) {
        self._shopname = shopname
        self._shopaddress = shopaddress
        self._clientName = clientName
        self._ClientAddress = ClientAddress
        self._PerferTime = PerferTime
        self._Cost = Cost
        self._date = date
        self._logo = Logo
    }
}
```

*Update*

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    guard orders.count > indexPath.row else {
        print("Index out of range")
        return
    }
    let order =  orders[indexPath.row]

    print(order.id)

}
```

Comment: Not related but please stop using private backing instance variables to get read-only constants. That's ridiculous in Swift. Just declare all variables as (non-optional) constants (`let`). And please conform to the naming convention that all variable names are supposed to start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: How do you want to construct the next view and accomplish the transition?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing object with prepareForSegue Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31164654/passing-object-with-prepareforsegue-swift)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no need to keep your data in reusable `UITableViewCell`. Cells are just displaying data. Use the `[Order]` array stored somewhere (`UIViewController` that contains this table view for example) instead.

And get the`order_id` from this array with index from `UITableViewDelegate` method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

Like:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    guard orders.count > indexPath.row else {
        print("Index out of range")
        return
    }
    let order =  orders[indexPath.row]
    if <#You want to present new VC via navigation controller#> {
        navigationController?.pushViewController(<#OrderDetailsViewController#>, animated: true)
    }else{
        <#Do some other presentation#>
}
```

Comment: I didn't keep my data in reusable UITableviewCell. I have [Order] in view controller. I still didn't get how i get order_id from `indexPath.row`. I will present the order details with perform segue.  @Dmitrii

Comment: Your JSON response contains array of orders with its id's. Why don't you have  order_id property in the Order model? @leo0019

Comment: can you please check my updated answer. it doesn't return the values on table or anything when I add this functio. I saved the id in the array

Comment: the updated code would't be compiled until you add the "id" property to your Order model class. If u did it u can get the id from array when user selecting this cell. And present details with this id

Comment: it's in Order model class!

Comment: Ok. Doesn't it mean what the question is complete? You have the id and ability to create new order details view object with this id as a initialization param

Comment: ok everything seems to be ok but when i tap on the cell it doesn't print the id

Comment: is the orders array serialized from JSON completely? what can u see if added a breakpoint on print(order.id) line? The array is valid?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143945/discussion-between-dmitrii-and-leo0019).