# How to pass array values from Protocol of a ViewController to another ViewController

Tags: swift, dictionary, delegates, protocols, viewcontroller

Explanation of what I want to do:

- I want to Create a **let params : [String: AnyObject]** Array/Dic that holds **[ name
  : nameTextField.text, pass : passTextField.text, etc... ]** in one
  ViewController called **"SignUpVC"**
- Also inside **"SignUpVC"** I want a protocol to hold my values for
  **params** and "**save**" them for later use in other ViewControllers. Without using NSUserDefaults.
- Now with those **params** being saved and assigned to the **protocol's
  function's parameters**, I want to go into another ViewController called
  "**SchoolSelectionVC**" and bring up those values and assign the
  **params** to a **var newParams : [String : AnyObject]** so they equal the same thing but ill be able to change some of the values if
  I wanted to...

So basically, I am trying to assign some values with the user input from SignUpVC, save those values, and bring them over to another variable in another ViewController for further use or change.

**Problem:**

Below is my code, and it shows that i am creating a **SignUpVC protocol**, a delegate called "**var signupDelegate = SignUpVCProtocol**", a **let param**, assigning it values, trying to assign the **let param** to the **SignUpVC Protocol parameters**, then move into another ViewController ("**SchoolSelectionVC**"), but the error stops it there. This all happens inside a button click action inside **SignUpVC**.

I just want to know why the delegate variable holding the SignUpVCProtocol and its function is giving me an error when I try passing the parameters to it.

If there are any tips on how to save values from one VC to another, let me know and if any of my code needs more explanation let me know too!

Code:

```
    protocol SignUpVCProtocol {
    func logInData(params : [String : AnyObject])
}

class SignUpVC: UIViewController{

    //MARK:- @IBOutlet
    //MARK: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    @IBOutlet var signUpWithFacebookButton: UIButton!
    //MARK:- Properties
    //MARK: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    var selectedTextField : UITextField!
    var keyboardPresent = false
    var loginFlag = false
    var fbId: String!
    var picUrl: String!
    var schoolID : String = ""
    var schoolDict : [String:AnyObject]!
    var player: AVPlayer?
    var fbData : AnyObject!
    let domainLbl = UILabel()

    var signUpDelegate : SignUpVCProtocol!  //Delegate var for Protocol
```

Inside a Button Action:

```
    let params = [
                    "Action"   :   "signUp" as AnyObject,
                    "name"     :   self.nameTextField.text! as AnyObject,
                    "email"    :   "\(self.emailTextField.text!)" as AnyObject,
                    "password" :   self.passwordTextField.text! as AnyObject,
                    "school"   :   self.schoolTextField.text! as AnyObject,
                    "device_token"   : sharedAppdelegate.DeviceToken as AnyObject,
                    "device_type"    : "iphone" as AnyObject,
                    "school_id"      :   self.schoolID as AnyObject
                ]
                self.signUpDelegate.logInData(params: params) //!!Where i want to assign the above params to the protocol params for use in SchoolSelectionVC
                //ERROR HAPPENS RIGHT ABOVE^^
                let schoolVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SchoolSelectionVC") as! SchoolSelectionVC
                let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: schoolVC)
                navVC.isNavigationBarHidden = true
                schoolVC.delegate = self
                self.present(navVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

    //in another VC Class
    extension SchoolSelectionVC: SignUpVCProtocol
    {
        func logInData(params: [String : AnyObject]) {
            self.newParams = params as! [String : String]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use protocols to pass data between viewControllers, use

> func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)

instead.

Check this answer:
[Passing object with prepareForSegue Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31164654/passing-object-with-prepareforsegue-swift)

For viewControllers you need to load programmatically you can use this example of passing data:

```
//For using without navigation controller
let vc = SomeViewController(nibName: "SomeViewController", bundle: nil);
vc.someVariable = someData
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

//For using with navigation controller
let vc = SomeViewController(nibName: "SoveViewController", bundle: nil);
vc.someVariable = someData
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: Thanks man! I had to replace a lot of the functionality with how things transition in this app, but i made it possible none the less and working too, seems like loading viewcontrollers programmatically doesnt leave much room for functionality when things get messy, but this way was a quick override of a method and done! Thanks again.

Comment: @amirkrd, you are not right. Passing data to viewController which will be loaded programmatically is easier then passing data to viewController which will be loaded using "performSegue". I've updated answer. You just need to initialize viewController and then you can access variable you need.